# Trying to bind props to v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify.js and trying to create a component which can be reusable across the application. Although its working absolutely fine, but I am not sure if it's the correct way.

I am creating a navigation drawer component which has the same menu options all the time but it can be opened from UI elements.

Below is the code.

// NavigationBar.vue

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    temporary
    v-model="drawerFlag"
    light
    overflow
    fixed
  >
    <v-list>
      <v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile-action @click.stop="toggleDrawer()">
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>close</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-list-tile-action>
      </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
    <v-list class="pt-0">
      <template v-for="item in items">
        <v-list-tile :key="item.title" :to="item.link">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
      </template>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['drawer'],
    data() {
      return {
        items: [
          { title: 'Home', icon: 'home', link: '/home'},
          { title: 'History', icon: 'history', link: '/history' },
          { title: 'Wallet', icon: 'account_balance_wallet', link: '/wallet' },
          { title: 'My Profile', icon: 'person', link: '/profile' },
          { title: 'Settings', icon: 'settings', link: '/settings' },
          { title: 'About', icon: 'error', link: '/about' },
          { title: 'Logout', icon: 'power_settings_new', link: '/logout' },
        ]
      };
    },
    computed: {
      drawerFlag: {
        get: function() {
          return this.drawer
        },
        set: function() {

        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleDrawer: function() {
        this.$emit('emitToggleDrawer');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

//Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="full-screen">
    <navigation-bar :drawer="drawer" v-on:emitToggleDrawer="toggleDrawer"></navigation-bar>
    <v-btn icon class="mt-3 fixed-position" @click.stop="drawer = !drawer">
      <v-icon>menu</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'home',
    data() {
      return {
        drawer: null
      };
    },

    computed: {
      user() {
        return this.$store.getters.user;
      }

    },

    methods: {
      toggleDrawer: function () {
        this.drawer = !this.drawer;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

In the above code..

In parent component, I have button to open navigation-drawer and the state of the navigation drawer is maintained in the parent component called "drawer". Then, I am passing "drawer" as a prop to child component and a method to trigger an event from child component to parent component called "emitToggleDrawer".

In child component, I am using vuetify.js navigation-drawer which takes v-model="drawerFlag", where drawerFlag is a computed property. When i tried to use v-model="drawer" i.e. binding to the prop I was getting an error. Then we can close the navigation drawer by clicking an element inside the navigation-drawer. To achieve that, I am calling a method of the component which later on emits an event which is listened by parent component.

Comment: why are you redefining 'drawer' as 'drawerFlag', because it is already registered in Home.vue data(), and you provide it as a props to component, can't you directly access it as 'drawer'?

Comment: The problem is in the child component when we try to use v-model="drawer" then its giving an error saying " Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "drawer" ".

Comment: so another approach would be that in NavigationBar.vue you can define  drawerFlag in data() also rt?

Comment: so it can attach getter and setter methods automatically

Comment: When you define 'drawerFlag' in data, it only gets set for the initial time. On changing the "drawer" from parent it does not reflect in the data property.

Comment: Initial State : 
`props: drawer: null
data: drawerFlag: false`

On clicking button on parent component to open the drawer.
`props: drawer: true,
data: drawerFlag: false`

Comment: You are correct on your part but what is wrong in this: Initial State: data: drawer:false props: drawer: false. this will also work, despite this your approach is correct props down and emit up.

Comment: The initial state is correct. But when the prop value gets changed, it does not reflect in the data value. Hence the functionality itself is not working.

Answer (score 10):

I solved it like this:

App.vue

```
<my-drawer ref="drawer"></my-drawer>
<my-header @toggle-drawer="$refs.drawer.drawer = !$refs.drawer.drawer"></my-header>
```

MyDrawer.vue

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer">
...
data() {
  drawer: true
}
```

MyHeader.vue

```
<v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="$emit('toggle-drawer')"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
```

---

It seems to me that we need `v-model="drawer"` on custom drawer component so it can properly work on all screen sizes.

Thus we need to change it's value from parent (or sibling) somehow also, that's why I'm using [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on drawer component.
Maybe instead of changing `$refs.drawer.drawer` data I could call drawers functions instead. I'm not sure what would be better approach. But this was the only simple solution that worked for me on all screen sizes.

So in my case, I'm changing drawer state only from header, but I think you can use this and fit according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the similar problem like below.

- Using just `drawer` instead of using `drawer` and `drawerFlag`
- Without having extra button on child component
- Without emitting `event` from child to parent
- Using `watch` in child component

**Home.Vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="full-screen">
    <navigation-bar :drawer="drawer"></navigation-bar>
    <v-btn icon class="mt-3 fixed-position" @click.stop="drawer = !drawer">
      <v-icon>menu</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import NavigationBar from '@/components/NavigationBar';
  export default {
    name: 'home',
    data() {
      return {
        drawer: true
      };
    },
    components: {
      NavigationBar
    }
  }
</script>
```

**NavigationBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    temporary
    v-model="drawer"
    light
    overflow
    fixed
  >
    <v-list class="pt-0">
      <template v-for="item in items">
        <v-list-tile :key="item.title" :to="item.link">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
      </template>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['drawer'],
    data() {
      return {
        items: [
          { title: 'Home', icon: 'home', link: '/home'},
          { title: 'History', icon: 'history', link: '/history' },
          { title: 'Wallet', icon: 'account_balance_wallet', link: '/wallet' },
          { title: 'My Profile', icon: 'person', link: '/profile' },
          { title: 'Settings', icon: 'settings', link: '/settings' },
          { title: 'About', icon: 'error', link: '/about' },
          { title: 'Logout', icon: 'power_settings_new', link: '/logout' },
        ]
      };
    },
    watch: {
       drawer (value) {
          return value;
       }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The solution you provided is not the right way. You should not modify props directly. By using v-model="drawer" you are binding props. You would be getting a warning in console when running vue.js in development mode.