# Change value fo v-model from other component with vuex

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I have 2 components 
1. it is sidebar navigation 1. header on the top, now i want to click from header to close, open sidebar navigation 
From sidebar code:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    :clipped="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp"
    fixed
    v-model="sidebar"
    app
    v-if="$store.state.isUserLoggedIn"
  >
```

in the computed i got the the update value from header action.

```
computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'sidebar'
    ])
  },
```

Now i want to update the value of `v-model 'sidebar'`

How can i do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46799241/1981247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the simple answer 
1. just change `v-model="sidebar"`  to `:value = "sidebar"`
remove sidebar on the `data`

Add sidebar to computed

```
computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'sidebar'
    ]),
  },
```

From the Header just add the action

```
this.$store.dispatch('setDrawer', !this.$store.state.sidebar)
```

and create mutations and actions  `setDrawer` in store file

some kind like that

```
state: {
    sidebar: true
  },
mutations: {
 setDrawer (state, sidebar) {
      state.drawer = sidebar
    }
} 
actions: {
setDrawer ({commit}, sidebar) {
      commit('setDrawer', sidebar)
    }
}
```